# Global variable not updating in Java

Tags: java, android, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I have a public static variable on my Main activity, so I can use it from other activities, I update it from activity#3 and check it's value and it's OK, but when I open an another activity for ex. activity#2 it returns the previous value like it's not updated.

I tried so far:

```
//activity#3
Main.myObject = new Object();
//returns the right (new Object's) value
```

and

```
Main.setMyObject(new Object());
Log.i("test", Main.myObject.Name()); //returns the right (new Object's) value

//activity#2
Log.i("test", Main.myObject.Name()); //returns the wrong (previous) value
```

but it returns the value that it got from the database at app start, if I reopen the app it returns the selected value(because it's stored in DB), but unable to get the right value at runtime.

Comment: you need to show more code... what is the difference of activity #2 and #3 etc...  show that in CODE.

Answer (score 1):

use a singleton pattern

```
class SingletonObject{
        private static SingletonObject instance;
        private Object object;
        private SingletonObject(){
            object = new Object();
        }

        public static synchronized SingletonObject getInstance() {
            if (instance == null){
                instance = new SingletonObject();
            }
            return instance;
        }

        public Object getObject() {
            return object;
        }

        public void setObject(Object object) {
            this.object = object;
        }
    }
```

usage

```
SingletonObject.getInstance().setObject(new Object());// or existing object

                Object object = SingletonObject.getInstance().getObject();
```

Comment: I tried it, does the same :( It shouldn't matter where I use it, right? Actually I'm using it in a ListAdapters' onclick event, but I think it shouldn't matter.

Comment: tried from another activity, still does the same the value is right on the current activity but wrong on the others :(

Comment: no matter where in use, the object is always the same

Comment: the code is exatly like the above, except the objectnames and other stuff that has nothing to do with it, doesn't matter since I found this: "Each class loader in Java has its own name space. One can load the very same class through two or more different class loaders. If this class is a singleton, then each of the class loaders used to load the class holds an own instance of the singleton." so it's not safe to store stuff in singleton between activities, I'm going to save the stuff in SQLite DB, but thanks for trying to help

Comment: as a singleton class should not be embedded in any class, otherwise it must be `public static class SingletonObject`

Comment: I tried, I also tried many ways of singleton in Android,  none of them worked

Answer (score 0):

Use "public static" modifier for your variable.

```
public static Object myObject = new Object;
```

Comment: You cannot treat an Activity as a POJO.  Never make anything in an Activity that can have a life time greater than the activity itself or you will get memory leaks.

Comment: I think you access the variable using the class instance variable. Access the variable using your class name.

Comment: then how should I create global variables, that can I use from different activities?

Comment: To use public static variable you do not need to create and class variable just type : classname.variable_name

Comment: it was just an example, it has to be an object, with variables and functions

Answer (score 0):

looks like in both the activities Main object is different. I mean activity 3 has reference of Main object which is different from main object in activity 2

Comment: how can I prevent creating multiple instances of Main activity?

Comment: making it singleton one way

Comment: I think Main activity can not  have multiple instances because it's oncreate event starts like
    
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

Answer (score 0):

You should never treat an `Activity` as a POJO.  The only way to create an `Activity` is via an `Intent` and the only way to pass data between activities is to use intent `Extra`.

There are two ways to solve this (amongst others).  Extend your `Application` class, in which case the variable truly is global, or create a base activity class and extend your activities from that.

Extending `Application` should only be done if you cannot do it any other way since global variables are usually a bad thing and are used to avoid writing correct code.

```
public BaseActivity extends Activity{

    protected object myVariableForAllActivities;

}

public MyActivity extends BaseActivity{

    myVariableForAllActivies = someValue;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to create a singleton in your application, outside of any other activity. That singleton will be returned to each application, and will be the same one, and it can store your object inside it:

```
class Config {
  private Config singleton;
  private Config() {}
  public static Config getInstance() {
    if (singleton != null) return singleton;
    singleton = new Config();
    return singleton;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You described the problem quite abstract, I will try an answer on some assumptions see if I got it right.
By activities I think you refer to threads. By main activity I understand the main thread.
However, if Main is an Object of a certain type with a public attribute, and that object is accessible by different threads then you have to control the access to its state( attributes) by those threads).
Also, If the Main object is passed between threads by copying it, and not reference it then you have  again the problem of getting previous objects.
My answer is do not use public attributes, there is no actual benefit from it. Use private attributes with getters and setters. This way you can:
- synchronized access from different threads;
- the initialisation with the new value is done in one single place (the setter).